# How do I calculate second largest value and add another column for it in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
features = ['c1']

secondLargest = all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].apply(
    lambda x:x.nlargest(2,features)).reset_index()

all_data = pd.merge(all_data, secondLargest.reset_index(),
    suffixes=["", "_secondLargest"], how='left', on=['Id'])
```

The problem with this code is:

1.) `secondLargest` variable also have a column named `level_1`

2.) When I merge the secondLargest variable with all_data, three columns gets merged `index`, `level_1`, `c1_secondLargest`, and I only want `c1_secondLargest`

3.) When I merge the secondLargest variable with all_data, The number of rows of all_data double.

Shape before merge: `(1000000,251)`
Shape after merge: `(2000000,251)`

Edit:

Input:

```
id   c1
1     3
1    34
1    75
2    84
2    54
2    23
2    96
3    55
3    76
```

Output:

```
id   c1   c1_secondLargest
1     3      34
1    34      34
1    75      34
2    84      84
2    54      84
2    23      84
2    96      84
3    55      55
3    76      55
```

Comment: Please provide example input data and desired output.

Comment: Basically, I just want to calculate the second largest value of all the column in `features` variable, and want to merge it with the main dataframe named `all_data`

Comment: Wait, I am editing the question

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay @JohnZwinck

Comment: Is your desire that "secondLargest" actually contains the largest value among those with the same id?  Why is it called "secondLargest" then, or do you actually want it to contain 34 for id==1 instead of 75 as you've written?

Comment: Yes, I want it to contain `75` because 75 is the largest value in `id` 1.

Comment: Ohhh damnnnn, I added the max instead of second max, and didn ot even realize, sorry, feeel soo stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('id')['c1'].apply(lambda x : x.max()).reset_index().rename(columns={'c1':'c1_secondLargest'}),on='id')
```

or:

```
print(df.merge(df.groupby('id')['c1'].apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(1)).reset_index().rename(columns={'c1':'c1_secondLargest'}).drop('level_1',axis=1),on='id'))


   id  c1  c1_secondLargest
0   1   3                75
1   1  34                75
2   1  75                75
3   2  84                96
4   2  54                96
5   2  23                96
6   2  96                96
7   3  55                76
8   3  76                76
```

Comment: Works thanks a lot, Just one thing,  can I add suffix instead of renaming all columns? Actually, my main dataframe have hundreds of columns.

Comment: @johndoe absolutely you can :) you should just this as an example and explore all options of `merge` sufficing your conditions. All the best..!!

Comment: Wait, your first answer just calculate `max`, I want `secondmax`. Let me try the second one

Comment: @johndoe : that is per the example output you provided you ca tweak it a little if you want

Comment: Sorry sorry @anky , I added the wrong output. Feel so stupid, anyway Thanks for the answer :D sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @johndoe thats fine. :) you can still use the same code and tweak a little. :)

Comment: Hey, I used your second answer and modified this `x.nlargest(2)` . I mentioned 3 problems, first two are solved. Third one exist. My dataframe rows doubled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186955/discussion-between-anky-91-and-john-doe).

Comment: `nLargest(2)` show, the `max` and `secondMax` value. That's why my rows doubled. If I add `nLargest(3)`, dataframe rows will triple, because they will include top 3

Answer (score 2):

Using `nth` + `sort_values`

```
df['second_largest'] = df.sort_values(by='c1').groupby('id').transform('nth', -2)
```

```
   id  c1  second_largest
0   1   3              34
1   1  34              34
2   1  75              34
3   2  84              84
4   2  54              84
5   2  23              84
6   2  96              84
7   3  55              55
8   3  76              55
```

Index alignment takes the resulting series and fits it back into the initial DataFrame.